# word for when you let something bad happen just to prove a point

Tags: single-word-requests

Anyone know the word you would use when you let something bad happen just to prove a point? "You're being _____."

For example, proactive would describe a situation where you attempt to prevent issues, reactive is where you respond after the fact. The word I'm looking for would be when an organization knows something bad could happen but allows it to prove a point or to teach a lesson. That organization could be said to be ______.

Comment: Negligent comes to mind.

Comment: Sounds like "malicious compliance".

Comment: The answers below are all good, but I wanted to comment that this could also be described (not defined) as "petty", and possibly "manipulative". Those may help.

Answer (score 5):

One way to say that would be

> You're cutting off your nose to spite your face.

This is a very common idiom, and well understood in all registers.

Comment: That's not it.  I need the word to use in this situation:  one person wants to let a computer crash so that the user learns a lesson.  My response would be something like "We can't be ______, we need to educate them ahead of time..."

Comment: @KeithPoss _That_ gap could be _spiteful_, but that doesn't really fit with how I originally read the question. Please expand ([edit]) the question with more context of how you want to use this word.

Comment: For example, proactive would describe a situation where you attempt to prevent issues, reactive is where you respond after the fact.  The word I'm looking for would be when an organization knows something bad could happen but allows it to prove a point or to teach a lesson.  That organization could be said to be ______.

Comment: @KeithPoss Those examples should go into the question. You can edit them into your question via the edit link just under your question.

Comment: Inactive has two forms; deliberate and negligent, and both can be considered as, *Contemptuous* and *Dismissive*. *Snide/snidely* works too - *derogatory or mocking in an indirect way.* Allowing people to make mistakes isn't  always a rude or bad thing though. Some people need to learn by the direct consequences of their action/inactions. In which case they may be giving them the opportunity to find out how 'not' to do something. That does not align with 'proving a point' which is often a biased personal action showing contempt.

Comment: I've never understood why people use "your face". You're supposed to want to harm the other, hence spiting "the face" not your face. Cutting off your nose to spite your face would be hurting yourself in the process of hurting yourself. I've never got this.

Answer (score 3):

After reading your question and associated comments several times, I conclude one of the words you're looking for is something like **vindictive** or a synonym, such as **spiteful**. From Cambridge:

> **[vindictive](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vindictive)**: having or showing a wish to harm someone because you think that they harmed you
>
> **[spiteful](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/spiteful)**: wanting to annoy, upset, or hurt another person, especially in a small way, because you feel angry towards them

Your example sentences with **vindictive**:

> *Anyone know the word you would use when you let something bad happen just to prove a point? "You're being **vindictive**."*
>
> *The word I'm looking for would be when an organization knows something bad could happen but allows it to prove a point or to teach a lesson. That organization could be said to be **vindictive**.*

In one of your comments, your state:

> *I need the word to use in this situation: **one person wants to let a
> computer crash so that the user learns a lesson**. My response would be
> something like "We can't be ______, we need to educate them ahead of
> time..."*

The intent here is clearly for the user to *learn a lesson* not for *educational* purposes but for *punishment* purposes. Perhaps this *one person* is angry with users for some reason, angry with a management decision, or frustrated by a perceived lack of resources -- only you would know their motivation. In any event, they seem to have an urge to punish, in which case you would fill in the blank with **vindictive** or a synonym thereof, e.g., **spiteful**.

I can't stop there. I understand that you might not want to use **vindictive** (or **spiteful**, etc.) in the sentence in which you reference *one person*. So, given that your question calls out terms such as *proactive* and *reactive*, you seem to be looking for something in between. One possibility is **hands off**. Again from Cambridge:

> **[hands off](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hands-off)**: Someone who has a hands-off way of organizing or dealing with something allows other people to make decisions about how things should be done and avoids becoming directly involved

In this case, the sentence re *one person* would read:

> *"We can't be **hands off**, we need to educate them ahead of time..."*

Based on the negative context of **vindictiveness**, I would probably say something like this:

> We can't be *knowingly* (or *intentionally*) **hands off**.

A good single word for being *knowingly* (or *intentionally*) **hands off** *when you should be **hands on*** is **negligent**, as suggested by @lux in a comment about two years ago. From Cambridge:

> **[negligent](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/negligent)**: not being careful or giving enough attention to people or things that are your responsibility:
>
> *"We can't be **negligent**, we need to educate them ahead of time..."*

Answer (score 1):

https://bulletproofmusician.com/productive-failure-how-strategic-failure-in-the-short-term-can-lead-to-greater-success-and-learning-down-the-road/

“Productive Failure”: A Teaching Method Which Leads to Short Term Failure, but Long Term Success

"That organization could be said to be engaged in a productive failure objective."